# How to parameterize the label clause in geom_text?

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, parameters

Would like to create a function with ggplot in it. How to can parameterize this label clause below that needs to vary across multiple function calls?

```
geom_text(aes(label = round(value, 3), 
geom_text(aes(label = round(value / 1e06, 0), 
geom_text(aes(label = 100 * round(value, 3),
```

I'm thinking: label = p_label - where p_label will be everything on the right of the equals sign up to the comma. Is this possible in R?

Passing a string does not work, tried c(), also no luck.

Comment: Define a function `p_label` that returns what you need depending on `value` or some other variable.

Comment: read about `aes_string`. or you can use `eval`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, M-M. realized this: can pass any string into the function, then inside it parse it as text and evaluate.